# Read a file and do something, multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading

This source is just an exemple:

```
inputf = open('input', 'r')
outputf = open('output', 'a')

for x in inputf:
    x = x.strip('\n')
    result = urllib2.urlopen('http://test.com/'+x).getcode()
    outputf.write(x+' - '+result+'\n')
```

I want to add threading to this to check a few URLs at the same time.
The user should everytime decide how many threads he want to use.
The order on the output is not important.

What is the best and most beautiful way for that?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You could use [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) and `imap` to get the results. Or make something with Twisted. This has been asked many times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` (or `multiprocessing.pool.Pool`)

like:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

n_threads = 5
pool = ThreadPool(processes=n_threads)

threads = [pool.apply_async(some_function, args=(arg1,)) for arg1 in args]

pool.close()
pool.join()

results = [result.get() for result in threads]
```